# How can I add users to a Facebook group automatically?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The flow I'm going for is:

- User signs in with Facebook to our site.
- User pays a fee using PayPal or some similar service.
- User is allowed access to a particular Facebook group.

I'm not particularly fussy about how the process works, but I'd like to avoid a manual step if possible.

I know I can't invite them using the Graph API (as they're not an [admin, developer or tester of the app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group/members)). But is there some other way round? A button that allows them to request access that I then confirm using the API? An automatic way of emailing an invite?

Or is there a way of making it easier to do the manual step? Some way of listing the new users with an "invite to group" button? A friend request button for the user to press?

Answer (score 2):

With facebook API you can't do this with a normal group, but you can use app groups instead. To create an app group, you have to do a POST request to this url:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{your-app-id}/groups
```

with the following informations:

- valid app access token
- name: the name of the group
- description: the description of the group
- privacy: enum, it can be open or closed
- admin: admin's user id

Then you will recive a gropu ID. You can get info about your group ith a GET request to this URL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{group-id}
```

**EDITED: You can no longer add members with POST request, but there is an another way.**

### New solution

You can use a client-side dialog to add members to groups. You can find the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/app-game-groups/v2.0#add_user

I tested it with a user who wasn't a tester, andd it works fine.

### Old solution (no longer available)

You can add members to this group with a POST request to this URL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{group-id}/members
```

You have to post:

- valid app access token
- member: user ID of the person to invite

The person will recive something like this image: [image: Your app's name has invited you to Your group's name]
<sub>(source: [edemmester.hu](http://edemmester.hu/sof_notify.png))</sub>

I tested it, it works fine.

More info about app groups: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/groups

IMPORTANT! You have to use **app access tokens** here, **not user access tokens**.

Comment: My understanding from the docs was that I could only invite them to the group if they are an admin, developer or tester of the app. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, I read the changelog and that way is no longer available for everybody, but I found an another way and tested it with an account who wasn't a tester, and it works fine, so you can use that. I edited my answer.

Comment: It looks like the new solution is also deprecated as of May 1 according to the link for the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to invite people without writing a browser extension that has access to the cookies etc. of the logged-in group admin.

Anyway, you cannot simply add people to a group [if you're not friends](https://www.facebook.com/help/190622277696378) with them, but need to [invite them by email](https://www.facebook.com/help/162550990475119). So probably it's easiest if you ask them for their email-address and then invite them by email.

Comment: Yeah, that email invite route might have to be the way to go. The browser extension idea is interesting, might give it a go!